# How to get Rails to insert a Foreign key constraint in DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby model called MyModelA and MyModelB as shown below

```
  class MyModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :mymodelb

  class MyModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Blah Blah Blah
```

When I create the database with rake db:create command, I notice that MYMODELA table doesn't have a foreign key constraint on it. I manually inserted it like this:

```
    ALTER TABLE MYMODELA ADD FOREIGN KEY (MYMODELB_ID) REFERENCES MYMODELB(ID);
```

How can I define my model such that this DB foreign key constraint is automatically created without me having to manually add it later?

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't provide a migration helper to add foreign_key. But you can use [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) gem

You do do this to add a foreign_key using foreigner gem

```
  create_table :products do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.integer :factory_id
    t.foreign_key :factories
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

generate a migration:

**rails g migration AddmymodelbidToMyModelA mymodelb_id:integer**

go the the migration file and add

**add_index :mymodela, :mymodelb_id**

just between the two end clauses

run **rake:db:migrate**

Comment: That won't create a foreign key inside the database though.